# adding items to <select> in IE5

Tags: javascript, html

Ill just awnser the first question... Why IE5 you wonder, Because its on a Windows CE device that im working with so im limited to use IE5. The application that i've made uses a webpage with a couple of elements.

I have two textfields and one list or `<select>`
I want to transfer the value of one textbox to the list. I've got it working in IE 10 and Chrome but when i tested the webpage on the device it did not send the value of textfield two to the list. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

This is my html code:

```
 <tr>
                    <td>Locatie:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="one" onkeyup="CheckOne()" name="locatie" value="{locatie}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bonregel:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bonregel" id="two" onkeyup="CheckTwo(event)" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bonlijst:</td>
                    <td><select id="selectbox" multiple></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Verzenden" id="sub" onclick="CheckContent()" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Velden Legen" id="reset" onclick="ClearFields()" /></td>
                </tr>
```

And then i have my javascript functions for adding the data to the list:

```
function AddToList(field) {
                // Create an Option Object
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                document.getElementById("selectbox").options.add(opt);
                opt.text = document.getElementById("two").value;
                opt.value = document.getElementById("two").value;
            }

function CheckTwo(event) {
                var field = document.getElementById("two").value;
                var tKey = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
                if (tKey == 51) {
                    AddToList(field);
                    GiveFocus("two");
                }
            }



// Gives focus to the specified component
            function GiveFocus(id) {
                document.getElementById(id).focus();
            }

            // Action that gets triggered by textfield 1
            function CheckOne() {
                if (event.keyCode == 13)
                    GiveFocus("two");
            }
```

**Edit**

I've figured out that the button takes priority for some kind of reason. The button submits as soon as i press enter. But when i press enter in the second textfield it should send the data to the list. Is there a solution so the button doesnt take priority

Heres a fiddle of my full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/3jywt8v1/1/

Comment: Might be worth checking: I think IE5 had JavaScript disabled by default.

Comment: @Mave Thanks for pointing that out, i've checked if the javascript is disabled but its not. The javascript is enabled on my device

Comment: Is it `document.getElementById("selectbox").add(opt)`? MDN states the add is on the [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add), not the `HTMLOptionsCollection`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright i always find it a bit weird to awnser my own questions, but i found a solution to my problem and i wanted to share it with the people that helped me.

I've figured out that in IE5 the `<select>` isnt very good to use as it comes to adding items with javascript. Thats why im using a `<textarea>` to store all the data. I've made the `<textarea>` a `readonly` field.

This is the Javascript that i use to make it work, and with make it work i mean to add the value of textbox 2 into the textarea.

```
function AddToList() {
                // Create an Option Object
                var box = document.getElementById("bonregels");
                var val = document.getElementById("two").value.toString();
                if (box.value != "")
                    box.value += "\n";
                box.value = box.value + val;                    
            }
```

Thanks everyone that helped, you pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

On IE5, you probably need to use the `Option` constructor rather than `createElement`:

```
function AddToList(field) {
    // Create an Option Object
    var val = document.getElementById("two").value;
    var opt = new Option(val, val);
    document.getElementById("selectbox").options.add(opt);
}
```

It also works on modern browsers.

I think `add`, what you're using, is the most compatible way to add the option to the list, but if that isn't it, you may need to add it via assignment instead:

```
var options = document.getElementById("selectbox").options;
options[options.length] = opt;
```

...but again, I think `add` was better supported in the 90s.

Comment: I've got the event triggered on the ENTER key, but when i press enter the button takes priority and submits the items. But the funny thing is the fields you see arent event in a <Form>. Do you know a way to make it that the button doesnt take priority

Comment: @CKY: Don't make the button a `type="submitt"`, use `type="button"`. When you're ready to submit the form, call `submit()` on the form element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, ive discoverd that the event is triggered really fast so IE5 kant keep up with it. So is there a way to delay the event

Comment: @CKY: What do you mean "really fast"? Which event? Yes, there are ways to delay responding to events, but I can't see any reason you'd need to here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code:

```
<form name=vv>
<select name="qq"></select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="add()">
</form>

function add() 
{
 var qq = document.vv.qq;
 var option = new Option("text", "0");
 qq.options[qq.options.length] = option;
}
```

Comment: How can this even work, i dont understand it completly.  Where do you get the text from and what does document.vv.qq mean?

Comment: vv is the form name (i.e. name="vv" in the form tag)
qq is the field name (i.e.  name="qq" in the select tag)

In old IE, it does not support DOM very well, so your code does not work.

Comment: But my code its more complicated then you'll expect ill make a fiddle and put it in the question

Comment: That doesnt really help if im honest, In my situation im using a textbox and the item should be added when i press a specific key.

Comment: Not to be rude and i really appreciate your help, but the fiddle doesnt even work

Comment: Will you paste your whole form to fiddle?